# Infinispan saving to cache in Weblogic server

Tags: transactions, infinispan

Below are my setup details:

Application Server: Weblogic 10.3
Infinispan version: 5.3.0.Final
Mode: Library Mode
Operating System: Linux
server setup: High availability

I am using TreeCache API since we migrated from JBoss Cache.

What I see is , when I run the code against normal linux or windows machines. put and get APIs works fine.

But when I run code against Weblogic server, put never succedded saying Transaction Failed. (XA Transaction). Note this happens when I do not use transactions.

I made this work , by declaring Transactions in xml config file as below:

```
 <transaction transactionManagerLookupClass="org.infinispan.transaction.lookup.GenericTransactionManagerLookup"

            lockingMode="OPTIMISTIC"

            transactionMode="TRANSACTIONAL"
    />
```

It still did not work.

Then I had to call weblogic UserTransaction , by following
"

```
@Resource
private static UserTransaction utx ;

utx = new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
```

and then use

```
   utx.begin();
   get node by fqn; 
   node.put(key,value);
   utx.commit();
```

It is only after doing above in quotes, that I see an entry in the cache and can retrieve it successfully

I want to understand why is it so ? Can I just not avoid using transactions?

Below is the xml config file:

```
    <global>
        <globalJmxStatistics    enabled = "true" />

        <transport clusterName = "CACHE_CLUSTER">
                <properties>
                        <property       name="configurationFile"
                                        value="tcp.xml" />
                </properties>
        </transport>

   </global>

   <default>

        <clustering mode="replication">
                <async asyncMarshalling="true" useReplQueue="true" replQueueInterval="10" replQueueMaxElements="100" />
                <stateTransfer timeout="2000000"/>
        </clustering>

        <transaction
            transactionManagerLookupClass="org.infinispan.transaction.lookup.GenericTransactionManagerLookup"
            lockingMode="OPTIMISTIC"
            transactionMode="TRANSACTIONAL"
            />

        <invocationBatching             enabled                 = "true"/>
        <jmxStatistics enabled="true"/>
   </default>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend that you move of the Tree API and you use the normal Map API, which is simpler to use and can be used both with and without transactions. The Tree API did require batching, which forces to have transactions enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Galder. I selected treecache because we are migrating from JBoss Cache, the changes expected were minimal.

Comment: But I will seriously consider this option of switching to mapAPI. I had tried that earlier and it had worked like a charm.

Comment: Even using batching alone does not solve the issue. For this , I had posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240284/infinispan-with-treecacheapi

Comment: thank you for your response Galder. I am continuing on the same forum because the post description works the way I make it work on Weblogic two node High availability servers. But when i use the same code against standalone weblogic server. the transaction.commit() throws error saying "Transaction does not exist".. I want to get to the root , if this is issue with Infinispan or Weblogic server's transaction handling.